# How to call a method with completion handle in swift 3+

Tags: ios, swift3

I am very new to swift. I have a method like this.

```
public func prepareUrl (appendString:String,bindedParams:String,isAuthorized:Bool,isGet:Bool,jsonBody:[String:String],completion:@escaping(String)->Void)
{

    let baseUrl=Bundle.main.value(forKey: "GlobalURL")
    let urlString=baseUrl as! String+appendString as String+bindedParams as String
    Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .downloadProgress(queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility)) { progress in
            print("Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
        }
        .validate { request, response, data in
            // Custom evaluation closure now includes data (allows you to parse data to dig out error messages if necessary)
            return .success
        }
        .responseJSON { response in
            debugPrint(response)
    }


}
```

I have no idea how to call this method since it's having a completion handler part too. How can I call this method. Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

**NOTE** :This answer is for example . You need to change as per your needs

```
func getResponse(url: String, method : HTTPMethod,  parameter : [String : AnyObject], Alert : Bool,  callback: @escaping responseHandler) -> Void{

        Alamofire.request(API_PREFIX + url, method: method, parameters: parameter).validate().responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                if let result = response.result.value {
                    let JSON = result as! [String : AnyObject]
                    print("\(JSON as AnyObject)")
                    callback(JSON as AnyObject, true)
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
                callback({} as AnyObject, false)
            }
        }
    }
```

**Calling of method using closure**

```
self.getResponse(url: "", method: .post, parameter: ["Email" : "" as AnyObject, "Password" : "" as AnyObject], Alert: true) { (responseObject, success) in
            if success{

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

To call method like this:

```
self.prepareUrl(appendString: "www.some.com/api/likeLogin", bindedParams: "name=lee", isAuthorized: false, isGet: true, jsonBody: ["key":"value"]) { (returnString) in
    if returnString == "someValue" {
       //do something
    }
    else{
    }
}
```

And in the method, you should call the completion to return value, like:

```
.responseJSON { response in
    completion("aReturnString")
}
```

Although the method name is `prepareUrl`, it actually requests the WebApi, so it's better to rename it to `request`.